# Custom visibility settings not applying

Tags: forms

I'm trying to edit a module. It has per role visibility settings that work, but i added code to add per page visibility settings. The settings show in the module ui page but they don't save(they don't apply). Is something wrong with the code?

```
// Role-based visibility settings
  $default_role_options = $item->settings['roles'];
  $result = db_query('SELECT rid, name FROM {role} ORDER BY name');
  $role_options = array();
  foreach ($result as $role) {
    $role_options[$role->rid] = $role->name;
  }
  $form['role_vis_settings'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Role specific visibility settings'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
  );
  $form['role_vis_settings']['roles'] = array(
    '#type' => 'checkboxes',
    '#title' => t('Show item for specific roles'),
    '#default_value' => $default_role_options,
    '#options' => $role_options,
    '#description' => t('Show this item only for the selected role(s). If you select no roles, the block will be visible to all users.'),
  );

// Per-path visibility
  $form['visibility']['path'] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => t('Pages'),
    '#collapsible' => TRUE,
    '#collapsed' => FALSE,
    '#group' => 'visibility',
  );

  $access = user_access('use PHP for settings');
  if (isset($block->visibility) && $block->visibility == BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP && !$access) {
    $form['visibility']['path']['visibility'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP,
    );
    $form['visibility']['path']['pages'] = array(
      '#type' => 'value',
      '#value' => isset($block->pages) ? $block->pages : '',
    );
  }
  else {
    $options = array(
      BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED => t('All pages except those listed'),
      BLOCK_VISIBILITY_LISTED => t('Only the listed pages'),
    );
    $description = t("Specify pages by using their paths. Enter one path per line. The '*' character is a wildcard. Example paths are %blog for the blog page and %blog-wildcard for every personal blog. %front is the front page.", array('%blog' => 'blog', '%blog-wildcard' => 'blog/*', '%front' => '<front>'));

    if (module_exists('php') && $access) {
      $options += array(BLOCK_VISIBILITY_PHP => t('Pages on which this PHP code returns <code>TRUE</code> (experts only)'));
      $title = t('Pages or PHP code');
      $description .= ' ' . t('If the PHP option is chosen, enter PHP code between %php. Note that executing incorrect PHP code can break your Drupal site.', array('%php' => '<?php ?>'));
    }
    else {
      $title = t('Pages');
    }
    $form['visibility']['path']['visibility'] = array(
      '#type' => 'radios',
      '#title' => t('Show block on specific pages'),
      '#options' => $options,
      '#default_value' => isset($block->visibility) ? $block->visibility : BLOCK_VISIBILITY_NOTLISTED,
    );
    $form['visibility']['path']['pages'] = array(
      '#type' => 'textarea',
      '#title' => '<span class="element-invisible">' . $title . '</span>',
      '#default_value' => isset($block->pages) ? $block->pages : '',
      '#description' => $description,
    );
  }

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => t('Save item'),
  );

  return $form;
}

/**
 */
function taskbar_ui_item_configure_validate($form, &$form_state) {
  // Ignore AHAH submission
  if (!empty($form_state['ahah_submission'])) {
    return;
  }

  if (isset($form_state['values']['ajax_refresh'])) {
    $rate = $form_state['values']['ajax_refresh'];
    if (!is_int($rate) && $rate < 0) {
      form_set_error('ajax_refresh', t('The refresh rate must be a positive integer.'));
    }
  }

  $item = taskbar_item_load($form_state['values']['name']);
  if ($function = taskbar_provider_get_function($item->provider, 'settings form validate')) {
    $function($form, $form_state, $item);
  }
}

/**
 */
function taskbar_ui_item_configure_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  // Ignore AHAH submission
  if (!empty($form_state['ahah_submission'])) {
    return;
  }
  $item = taskbar_item_load($form_state['values']['name']);
  $item->title = $form_state['values']['title'];
  $item->settings['text'] = $form_state['values']['text'];
  $item->settings['description'] = $form_state['values']['description'];
  $item->settings['ajax'] = !empty($form_state['values']['ajax']);
  $item->settings['refresh'] = !empty($form_state['values']['refresh']);
  $item->settings['update'] = !empty($form_state['values']['update']);
  $item->settings['ajax refresh'] = isset($form_state['values']['ajax_refresh']) ? $form_state['values']['ajax_refresh'] : 0;
  $item->settings['roles'] = array();
  foreach ($form_state['values']['roles'] as $rid => $value) {
    if ($value) {
      $item->settings['roles'][$rid] = $rid;
    }
  }

  if ($function = taskbar_provider_get_function($item->provider, 'settings form submit')) {
    $function($form, $form_state, $item);
  }

  taskbar_item_save($item);
  drupal_set_message(t('The block configuration has been saved.'));
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'admin/structure/taskbar';
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'it doesn't get saved'? Do you mean it doesn't get applied? It simply doesn't fire? As far as I can see you don't save anything here...

Comment: Yes it doesn't get applied, the per role visibility option gets applied though

Comment: So the title of you question better should be sth. like "How to apply custom visibility settings programmatically" or "Per page visibility doesn't get applied"

Comment: Ok no problem, i just changed it

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! May you show the full code of the first function? It is even missing the function name.